# Forward pagination with object mapper in java asyn

Tags: java, asynchronous, cassandra

Is there a way to implement the following asynchronously with MappedAsyncPagingIterable interface with CompletionStage mappedAsyncPage?

I want to implement a linkedin feed feature where first request fetches first 5 rows and the following requests will fetch the next 3 rows

```
@Override
 public List<Tuple2<String,CustomerRequest>> getCustomerRequestData(final String productId, PreparedStatement ps, final String receiptPeriod, String pagingState)
{
 final int PAGE_SIZE = 10;
 session = cassandraSessionFactory.getSession();
 final List<CustomerRequest> customerRequestdata = new ArrayList<CustomerRequest>();
 try
 {
  final BoundStatement boundStatement = ps.bind(productId, receiptPeriod, PAGE_SIZE);
  boundStatement.setPagingState(PagingState.fromString(pagingState));
  final ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(boundStatement);
  final Iterator<Row> iter = resultSet.iterator();
  final PagingState nextPage = resultSet.getExecutionInfo().getPagingState();
  int remaining = resultSet.getAvailableWithoutFetching();
  for (final Row rowdt : resultSet)
  {
  customerRequestdata.add(constructCustomerReq(rowdt));
  if (--remaining == 0)
   {
    break;
   }
  }
 }
 catch (final Exception e)
 {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return new Tuple2<>(nextPage.toString(), customerRe);
```